# $C^\infty$ change of charts

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am stuyding a bit about manifolds and, for this, consider the unitary sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Consider the atlas $\mathcal{A}=\{(\phi_j^{+-},U_j^{+-})|j=1,...,n+1\}$, where $$\phi_j^{+-} (x_1,...,x_{n+1}) = (x_1,...,{x_j^*},...,x_{n+1})$$, where $x_j^*$ means that we "delete" the j-th coordinate and $$U_j^{+} = \{(x_1,...,x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb{S}^n | x_j>0\}$$ and $U_j^{-}$ means the same, but with $x_j<0$.

My attempt is to show that the change of charts is $C^\infty$, but honestly, none of my attempts seem to be nice. Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Where are you having trouble? First compute $U_1^{+}\cap U_2^{+}$. Then compute $\phi_2^{\pm}\circ(\phi_1^{\pm})^{-1}$ when restricted appropriately. The rest is a matter of fiddling with indices and $\pm$ as appropriate. To be concrete, just do it for $S^1\subset\Bbb{R}^2$. The general case is literally extra notation.

Comment: Write down the inverse map of $\phi_j^\pm$. Consider the maps $(\phi_i^\pm)\circ (\phi_j^\pm)^{-1}: U_i^\pm \cap U_j^\pm \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, where $i>j$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo honestly, it is not very clear to me what I have to show to conclude that the change of charts is $C^\infty$. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Take a very specific pair. For instance $\phi_1^+$ and $\phi_2^+$. Calculate the inverse $(\phi_1^+)^{-1}$. Then, compose to get $(\phi_2^+)\circ(\phi_1^+)^{-1}$. Write this out explicitly $((\phi_2^+)\circ (\phi_1^+)^{-1})(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)=(\dots)$. This gives you a relatively nice formula. Surely you know how to check whether or not a given function, when written down explicitly, is $C^{\infty}$ or not.

Comment: For $1<j<i<n$, we have that $(\phi_i^+)^{-1} (y_1,...,y_n)= (y_1,...,\sqrt{1-\sum_i y_i^2},...,y_n)$, therefore, $(\phi_2^+)\circ (\phi_1^+)^{-1} (y_1,...,y_n)= (y_1,...,y^*_j,...,\sqrt{1-\sum_i y_i^2},...,y_n)$, which is $C^\infty$, right?

Comment: You wrote $(\phi_2^+)\circ(\phi_1^+)^{-1}$ on the left, but you have $y_j$ omitted on the right, but I assume this is just a typo. But yes, this is the idea, and clearly as you see from the formula, it is $C^{\infty}$ (because the domain of $y$'s is such that the thing inside the square root is strictly positive so that term, which is really the only potentially troublesome term, is $C^{\infty}$). If you really want to prove things in the general case, then just be careful with the super/subscripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$U_j^\epsilon = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) \in S^n \mid \epsilon x_j > 0 \}\ $$
where $\epsilon$ stands for a $+$ or $-$ sign. The map $\phi_j^\epsilon$ deletes the $j$-th coordinate; its image is the open unit ball $D^n = \{(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \mid \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 < 1 \}$. Clearly $\phi_j^\epsilon$ is the map obtained from the projection map $p^j : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R^n$ which deletes the $j$-th coordinate by restricting domain and codomain to $U_j^\epsilon$ and $D^n$, respectively. The map $p^j$ is $C^\infty$.

The inverse $(\phi_j^\epsilon)^{-1} : D^n \to U_j^\epsilon$ is obtained from
$$\psi_j^\epsilon : D^n \to \mathbb R^{n+1}, \psi_j^\epsilon(y_1,\ldots,y_n) = (y_1,\ldots,y_{j-1},\epsilon\sqrt{1- \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2}, y_j,\ldots, y_n)$$
by restricting codomain to $U_j^\epsilon$. Also $\psi_j^\epsilon$ is $C^\infty$.

We have $U_j^+ \cap U_j^- = \emptyset$ and $U_j^\epsilon \cap U_i^\delta =  \{x = (x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1} \in S^n \mid \epsilon x_j > 0, \delta x_i > 0 \} \ne \emptyset$ for $i \ne j$. We do not need the explicit descriptions of $\phi_j^\epsilon(U_j^\epsilon \cap U_i^\delta)$ and $\phi_i^\delta(U_j^\epsilon \cap U_i^\delta)$; it suffices to know that they are open subsets of $D^n$. The transition map
$$\tau = \phi_i^\delta \circ (\phi_j^\epsilon)^{-1} : \phi_j^\epsilon(U_j^\epsilon \cap U_i^\delta) \to \phi_i^\delta(U_j^\epsilon \cap U_i^\delta)$$
is given by
$$\tau(y_1, \ldots,y_n) =  p^i(\psi_j^\epsilon(y_1, \ldots,y_n)) .$$
By the chain rule $p^i \circ \psi_j^\epsilon : D^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is $C^\infty$. But $\tau$ is obtained from $p^i \circ \psi_j^\epsilon$ by restricting domain and codomain to open subsets of $D^n$ and $\mathbb R^n$, respectively. Thus $\tau$ is $C^\infty$.

Instead of invoking the chain rule one can also explicitly compute
$$\tau(y_1, \ldots,y_n) = (y_1,\ldots,y_{j-1},\epsilon\sqrt{1- \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2}, y_j,\ldots, y_n)_{*i}$$
where the index $*i$ means that the $i$-th coordinate of the vector is deleted. All coordinate functions of $\tau$ are obviously $C^\infty$, thus $\tau$ is $C^\infty$.